why findIndex can not get correct result
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.27;

library ArrayLib {
    function find(uint[] storage arr, uint num) internal view returns (uint) {
        for(uint i =0; i< arr.length; i++) {
            if(arr[i] == num) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        revert("not found");
    }
}


contract TestArray {
    uint[] public arr = [1,2,3,4];

    function findIndex(uint num) external view returns (uint) {
        return ArrayLib.find(arr, num);
    }
}

I try to use lib function, but findIndex can not get correct result
I want to get the correct result
